# Not Looping? HTML5 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have no idea why this code does not loop as it should.  My mind is blown and hopefully someone can give me a hand.  This is my first attempt into the HTML5 and JavaScript world and my first StackOverflow post.  My background is in java so that should explain the quirks in my code. By the way, if you run the code the canvas and balls will show up, just not move.

First off, here is the HTML5

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>ChainReaction5</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chain_reaction.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <body onLoad="init();">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400">
    Your browser dosen't support the HTML5 canvas.</canvas><br />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Secondly here is the js

```
    //gobal vars
    var context;
    var box;
    var balls;

    var defaultBallX=240;
    var defaultBallY=190;
    var defaultBallRad=6;
    var defaultBallV=5;

    var defaultNumBalls=10;

    //box class
    function Box() {
        var boxx=20;
        var boxy=20;
        var boxWidth=460;
        var boxHeight=360;

        this.getX = function() {return boxx;}

        this.getY = function() {return boxy;}

        this.getWidth = function() {return boxWidth;}

        this.getHeight = function() {return boxHeight;}

        this.getBalls = function() {return ball;}

        this.paintMe = function() {
            context.fillStyle = "black";
            context.strokeRect(boxx, boxy, boxWidth, boxHeight);
        }
    }

    /*  Box Class
     *  this class is sloppy but more memory efficent
     */
    function Ball(x, y, radius, vx, vy, color) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.radius=radius;
        this.vx=vx;
        this.vy=vy;
        this.color=color;   

        this.paintMe = function() {
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(this.x, this.y, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
            context.fillStyle = this.color; 
            context.fill();
        }
    }

    Array.prototype.appendBalls = new function(array) {}
    Array.prototype.clearBalls = new function() {}

    Array.prototype.appendBalls = function(array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                balls.push(array[i]);
            }
        }

    Array.prototype.clearBalls = function() {
            balls = new Array();
        }

    // begin program
    function init() {
        context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d"); 
        box = new Box();
        balls = new Array();
        balls.appendBalls(createBalls(box, defaultNumBalls));
        setInterval(moveBall(balls, box), 100);
    }

    function createBalls(box, numBalls) {
        var locBalls = new Array(numBalls);
        for (var i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
            var randx = randp(50, 400)
            var randy = randp(50, 300);
            var randr = Math.random()*defaultBallRad+1;
            var randvx = randv();
            var randvy = randv();
            var randc = randColor();
            locBalls[i] = new Ball(randx, randy, randr, randvx, randvy, randc);
        }
        return locBalls;    

        function randv() {
            var neg = 1;
            if (Math.random()>.5) neg = -neg;
            return Math.random()*defaultBallV*neg;  
        }

        function randp(low, hight) {
            if (low < 0) low = 0;
            var p = -1;
            while (p > hight || p < low) {
                p = Math.random()*hight;
            }
            return p;
        }

        function randColor() {
            var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
            var color = '#';
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
                color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
            }
            return color;
        }
    }
    function moveBall(balls, box) {
        clear(this.box);
        this.box.paintMe();

        for (var i = 0; i < this.balls.length; i++) {
                moveAndCheck(this.balls[i], this.box);
            }
    }

    function moveAndCheck(b, box) {

        if ((b.x+b.vx+b.radius-1)>(this.box.boxWidth+this.box.boxx) || b.x+b.vx-b.radius<this.box.boxx+1) {
            b.vx = -b.vx;
        }
        if ((b.y+b.vy+b.radius-1)>(this.box.boxHeight+this.box.boxy) || b.y+b.vy-b.radius<this.box.boxy+1) {
            b.vy = -b.vy;
        }

        b.x += b.vx;
        b.y += b.vy;

        b.paintMe();

    }

    function clear(box) {
        context.clearRect(this.box.boxx, this.box.boxy, 
        this.box.boxWidth, this.box.boxHeight);
    }
```

Comment: Have you already checked if you're getting any runtime errors that may be stopping your JavaScript from continuing?

Comment: Not sure it's related at all, but you should use the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` for HTML5 documents.

Comment: Browsers actaully tolerate the dual body tags (though it is invalid HTML and should definitely be fixed), the DOCTYPE is also irrelevant here (no one uses XHTML on the web, they serve the documents as text/html so they are treated as plain HTML, regardless of the DOCTYPE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank the people who contributed to my question and it has been helpful in resolving the issue and the answer I selected was current in a way, but it fixed the problem for a different reason.

Incorrect:

> Putting quotes around 'moveBalls(balls, box)' animates things.

What actually fixes the problem is removing the arguments and parentheses from the call to the moveball function.  I discovered this when rewriting other parts of my code as the poster suggested.

So for future notice to other people with a similar problem if you need to remove the arguments and use a wrapper function or global variables.

Comment: You asked how to get the function working—you got that. If you wanted a code review, there is plenty of scope for improvement. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The first time I tried running it I got the following in the Firebug console:

> useless setInterval call (missing quotes around argument?)
>   [Break On This Error] setInterval(moveBall(balls, box), 100);

Putting quotes around 'moveBalls(balls, box)' animates things.

Incidentally, you can use prototype inhertiance to make your function a bit more efficient, the methods in Box are given to each instance. To have them inherit the methods, put them on the constructor's prototype:

```
Box.prototype = {

    getX: function() {return this.boxx;},

    getY: function() {return this.boxy;},

    getWidth: function() {return this.boxWidth;},

    getHeight: function() {return this.boxHeight;},

    getBalls: function() {return this.ball;},

    paintMe: function() {
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.strokeRect(this.boxx, this.boxy, this.boxWidth, this.boxHeight);
    }
};
```

Note that in javascript, a function's *this* keyword is set by the call, it is not set by how you declare the function (though you can use ES5 *bind*, but that is not widely supported yet).

Some other hints:

In the Box constructor you are making local variables but you really want to assign them to the new Box instance, so use *this* instead of *var*:

```
function Box() {
    this.boxx=20;
    this.boxy=20;
    this.boxWidth=460;
    this.boxHeight=360;
}
```

In the *clearBox* function, you are using *this* when it is not set in the call, so it references *window*. Just get rid of it, you pass *box* to the function so reference it directly:

```
function clear(box) {
    context.clearRect(box.boxx, box.boxy, 
    box.boxWidth, box.boxHeight);
}
```

Same applies to the *moveBall* and *moveAndCheck* functions, just get rid of *this* (I think you should do some research on how *this* is handled in javascript, there are many articles on it, it's quite different to Java).
Now the balls will bounce around nicely inside the box.

Comment: `setInterval(function(){moveBalls(balls,box)},100)` is more efficient and faster than passing in a string.

Comment: That just wraps a global function call in another function that calls it. If you look at the code, the OP can just remove the formal parameters from *moveBalls* and do `setInterval(moveBalls, 100)` since *balls* and *box* are global variables. The OP has much to learn about getting this sort of function to work efficiently and nicely with other code, an answer that fixes it all would be very, very long.

Comment: It's not a 'just wraps' thing. Passing a function allows the function to be compiled once at compile time rather than each iteration of the loop at run time. The difference in speed can be quite significant. I have personally seen apps where the frame rate doubles or triple when not passing a string to `setInterval`. FYI, `setInterval(function(){moveballs()},x)` is more closely related to `setInterval(moveballs,x)` - both pass functions, which is the important part.